# How to multiboot on 1 drive: Android desktop fork, Windows 10, Lubuntu, and Mac OSx?

Tags: osx, windows, dual-boot, lubuntu

**The problem**

I want to have 4 OS, an Android OS preferably [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/en/download_x86), Lubuntu, Windows 10, and Mac OS X on one hardrive in a similar manner to a dual boot just having 4 instead of 2.

**Specs**

- Model # [Acer Spin SP-513-51-51PB-N16W1](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/NX.GK4EK.006)
- CPU [Intel i5-6200U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88193/intel-core-i5-6200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz.html) @2.3 GHz dual core 4 logical cores
- Ram: 16 GB DDR4
- Hard drive: NVMe m.2 ssd 1 TB
- GPU: Intel HD 520
- OS: Dual boot of Windows 10 home Ver 1809 KB4497934 and Lubuntu 18.04.2

  - The Ram and SSD are upgrades

**Things I've tried**

Installing [Phoenix OS](https://www.phoenixos.com/en/download_x86#guide) by following [this](https://www.bouncegeek.com/dual-boot-phoenix-os/) guide to install, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749) post to make it show in grub. I tried using `sudo grub-update` to get it to show up when that failed to no avail.

**General info**

As I said in my specs I have Lubuntu and Windows 10 installed currently, but would rather not lose them if it all possible. I keep everything in a cloud so it's not the end of the world if I have to restart just a headache to restore that I'd rather not deal with.

Comment: @Freddy No offense but I don't really get where I need to clarify and asking me to give you more info doesn't really help when I don't know what details your missing. If you tell me what I'm missing I'll give it to you but otherwise I can't do much.

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite slow and need people to spell things out for me before I get them.

Comment: You are asking how to install multiple OSes on your laptop and there is no simple answer to that, especially for the hackintosh part. This alone would require a dozen of patches and tweaks like a different bootloader, patched ACPI tables, swapping kexts and more. Not to mention that installing OS X on PC hardware [isn't exactly legal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149366/how-to-quad-an-android-desktop-fork-windows-10-lubuntu-and-mac-osx-on-1-drive#comment1909991_1149366). And your linked Phoenix OS guide involves Windows to install the OS and I don't see how this is related to `grub`.

Comment: I see I always throught it was legal since you can download their os for free directy off their website as for the part about grub since it's the oad order in the bios boot page assumed grub just can't read it.

Comment: @MageintheBarrel That you can download something doesn't mean you have a license to use it as you please. Apple's license allows installation in Apple's hardware only, quite explicitly. Windows ISOs are as well freely downloadable but that doesn't mean you don't have to pay a license to use it. Also quite explicit in the EULA you have to agree with when installing. I suggest you pay more attention to the terms of service from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Since Phoenix OS did not cooperate, and your CPU is [VT-x](https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-intel-virtualization-technology/) capable, perhaps virtualizing it, [Mac OS X](https://www.pcsteps.com/2157-mac-os-x-virtual-machine-vmware-player/#VirtualBox), and Lubuntu under Windows 10 is a viable solution; https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-in-virtualbox/ explains the process using Oracle's free [Virtual Box](https://virtualbox.org) app.